# How to set TO ADDRESS while sending an email in Hybris?

Tags: email, sap-commerce-cloud, reply

When user replies on a mail that he has received that should go to particular email id. I tried to give in `DefaultEmailGenerationService.java` but it didn't reflect.

Could any one suggest how it can be achieved?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your question, what exactly you are looking for? In which email flow you want to change(register, order notification, forgot password etc)? If you want the user can reply system email in that case you need to set proper `from email` for your `email template` so that when user reply that will become `to`.

Comment: There is a process in which whatever message/mail user receives if he replies on that should go to a specific email id.This is kind of service flow.

Comment: you can set `fromEmai`, so when user reply, the reply will go to `fromAdress`. Find my answer below.

Comment: can u also give how a email process is happening in hybris ?

Comment: Sure, soon I will publish a post on it. subscribe the [helphybris](https://www.helphybris.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Scenario 1:

> How to change fromEmail Address of an email in Hybris?

As I mentioned in the comment if you want to set `from emailAddress` you can do that using Impex. Just find out what is your emailPage and set `fromEmail` and `fromName`.

---

### Scenario 2:

> How to set fix toAdress in Hybris for all email?

If you want to send all emails to some fix `toAddress`, in that case, you need to override `email` and `displayName` in respective `*EmailContext` of `renderer template`.

Let's just assume you want to override `toAddress` in customer registration flow. So here you need to find context class name form impex. Below are the renderer template for customer registration subject & body and `CustomerEmailContext` is the class name which will feed all data to this renderer.Now you just need to populate those data in `init` method of `CustomerEmailContext.java`

---

### Scenario 3:

> How to support multiple toAddress and attachments in Hybris?

To support multiple toAddress & fromAddress, ccAddresses, bccAddresses and attachments.

- You need to create custom fields(toAddressList, ccAddresses etc) in
  your `*EmailContext` and populate the value.
- Override `generate` method of `DefaultEmailGenerationService` class.
- Fetch your value from `emailContext` like `emailContext.get("yourcustomFiled")`
- Modify `createEmailMessage` method in such way so you can pass all your custom fields(toAddressList, ccAddresses etc) to final `DefaultEmailService`

---

### You can find [detail post here](https://hybrisdeveloper.blogspot.in/2018/03/how-to-support-multiple-toaddress-and.html)

Comment: Thanks Scenario 2 helped me

Comment: I am glad it helps you!! you can mark my post as answered.