# How to set TO multiple addresses while sending an email in Hybris

Tags: email, sap-commerce-cloud

I am developing a wishlist functionality; there comes a requirement to give privilege to the customer to share a wishlist. When he clicks on share, a popup opens with two fields to input 1.) To mail addresses, 2) Some comments.

I wrote a VM template, event listener, a context class and a businessprocess.xml.
Now when I start the business process in the listener, it will invoke my context class; populates all the required attributes to the context and that context will be used to display dynamic stuff on the VM template.

But I could not find where I can actually input my TO ADDRESSES in this whole process.
My init method in the context class goes something like this.

```
{
    super.init(wishlistShareEmailProcessModel, emailPageModel);
    put("wishlistComments", wishlistShareEmailProcessModel.getComments());
    put("wishlistName", wishlistShareEmailProcessModel.getWishlistName());
}
```

kindly suggest me(I am using 6.3 btw)

Answer (score 2):

Override **EMAIL** property to set TO email address

```
{
    super.init(wishlistShareEmailProcessModel, emailPageModel);
    put("wishlistComments", wishlistShareEmailProcessModel.getComments());
    put("wishlistName", wishlistShareEmailProcessModel.getWishlistName());
    put(DISPLAY_NAME, "User Display Name"); //wishlistShareEmailProcessModel.getDisplayName()
    put(EMAIL, wishlistShareEmailProcessModel.getToEmail()); //wishlistShareEmailProcessModel.getToEmail()
}
```

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49403086/2478134)

---

**Edit:** To support multiple To email addresses refer below post

https://www.helphybris.com/2018/03/multiple-toaddress-attachment-in-email-hybris.html

Comment: Thank you,
But I have list of to email addresses; will the below code works 

put(EMAIL, wishlistShareEmailProcessModel.getWishlistToEmailAddresses());

I mean will it accept list of strings

Comment: refer this [multiple-toaddress-in-email-hybris](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/03/multiple-toaddress-attachment-in-email-hybris.html) post